# A-frame font border?

Tags: aframe

How can I give a border to each letter form a `a-text`-tag? I need something like this but with A-frames `a-text`-tag:

```css
p {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

```html
<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

**Update:** I've next situation: Inside my scene I've made some gazebuttons and because you don't know what this buttons do, I've added some text to this buttons. The problem is when I do use a static color for the text in the buttons. Default I use a black color, but on a black background, the text is unreadable. So I'll add a withe border to that text so you could read it.

So the text must stand inside the scene and must rotate inside this scene. In the example code of @ngokevin, the text got a static position.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-html-shader

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-html-shader@0.2.0/dist/aframe-html-shader.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-plane material="shader: html; target: #planeHTML" position="0 2 -6"></a-plane>
    </a-scene>

    <!-- HTML to render as a material. -->
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden">
      <div id="boxHTML" style="background-image: url(cheesecake.png); color: white; width: 500px; height: 500px; font-size: 64px; font-family: monospace; text-align: center">
        <p style="background: rgb(30, 30, 30); position: absolute; top: 25px; width: 500px">CHEESECAKE FOR YOU</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden">
      <div id="planeHTML">
        <p style="text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not really what I need, I've updated my question.